# Correction in VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Below mentioned code is written by [@simoco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067523/simoco). I need a small correction. The code works for two range. I want the code to only run for columns `A:E`. In other words, currently if I select a cell in any columns other than `A:E`, when the code is run only two cells are selected. I do not want that to happen. If I select any cell in `A:E`, I want `A:E` to be selected. If I do not select a cell in columns `A:E`, then code should not run and a message box should appear:

```
msgbox("Please select a cell in columns A:E").
```

Please help.

The code is:

```
Sub test1()
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Range
Dim rngAE As Range, cell As Range

With Selection
For Each ar In .Areas
    If rng Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = ar.Resize(1, 2)
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, ar.Resize(1, 2))
    End If
Next ar

Set rngAE = Intersect(.Cells, Range("A:E"))
If Not rngAE Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngAE
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A" & cell.Row & ":E" & cell.Row))
    Next cell                
End If
End With

rng.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
Set rngAE = Intersect(.Cells, Range("A:E"))
If Not rngAE Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngAE
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A" & cell.Row & ":E" & cell.Row))
    Next cell                
End If
```

to this:

```
Set rngAE = Intersect(.Cells, Range("A:E"))
If Not rngAE Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngAE
        Set rng = Union(rng, Range("A" & cell.Row & ":E" & cell.Row))
    Next cell 
Else
    msgbox "Please select a cell in columns A:E", vbCritical     
    Exit Sub          
End If
```

Comment: Hi ARich, thanks for your reply. I got altered the code. But in my code i want this to be removed. I mean I dont want these code to work. Set rng = ar.Resize(1, 2)
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, ar.Resize(1, 2))
    End If....

Comment: Hi ARich, ones again thanks. I ones again checked. It worked perfectly. thank you again.